# Cannot Install Oracle Java 8

Tags: java, dpkg, oracle, android-studio

I'm extremely new to Ubuntu. With that said, I have followed for hours commnands to install and uninstall Java 8. I am trying to get Android Studio to work. I uninstalled Java 7 as it required 8 but I can't seem to get it to work. I have removed the installer by deleting the whole folder:

```
sudo rm -r /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/
```

Then I run:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get purge oracle-java8-installer
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

The response I get:

```
download failed
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of oracle-java8-set-default:
 oracle-java8-set-default depends on oracle-java8-installer; however:
  Package oracle-java8-installer is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-set-default (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
 oracle-java8-set-default
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'd appreciate help on this and I'll be very responsive. I can't move forward until this is resolved. Thank you

Comment: Please try this `sudo dpkg --configure -a`